# Switch ViewControllers of different heights in Container View

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uicontainerview, childviewcontroller

I have a requirement where I have to load different UI based on selected option in a ViewController. Here is the representation

[image]

Option1 and Option2 are radio buttons and user is allowed to select only one option at a time. Based on the selection, below area has to be updated with different textfields.

So, I created a view below the options which acts as a container. Created two ViewControllers with textFields for Option1 and Option2 which will be added a child view controllers to the containerView. Below is the hierarchy of the mainViewController

--> View

------> ScrollView

------------> ContentView

------------------> Label

------------------> Label

------------------> Option1

------------------> Option2

------------------> ContainerView

Based on selected option, I load respective viewController as childViewController to the containerView.

The point to note is, number of fields for option1 and option2 are different and height of the containerView should be adjusted based on the number of subviews in selected option, so that the complete screen is scrollable.

I couldn't able to resize option1 and option2 viewControllers based on the number of fields(subviews) in it.

How can I adjust the height of childViewControllers based on number of fields and set containerViews height?

Or what would be the better approach to achieve such design?

Comment: Do you have enough vertical space to hold the full "Option 2" view? If so, then simply adjust the size of the view when you add it to your Container view. If not, you may need to use scroll views.

Answer (score -1):

> How can I adjust the height of childViewControllers based on number of fields

This depends on the content in the child view controllers.

> set containerViews height?

Once you've added the child view to the container. Call containerView.sizeToFit() and it will adjust its size to fit the child view.

Note: Make sure you don't have constraints on the container view restricting its height or it won't be able to adjust.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622630-sizetofit